# NGINX Setup with WordPress Multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I wanted to know the configuration for WordPress Multisite when the main site is in the root and the others in /site-name/

For example:

`Main website: http://www.example.com/ Second website: http://www.example.com/second-site/ Third site: http://www.example.com/thrid-site/`

I looked for the setting, but I only found it with subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your folder structure is as follows:

```
/root_folder/*
/root_folder2/second-site/*
/root_folder3/third-site/*
```

Then you need:

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    
    root /root_folder/;
    
    location / {
        # code
    }
    
    location /second-site {
        root /root_folder2/;
        # code
    }

    location /third-site { 
        root /root_folder3/;
        # code
    }
}
```

It's important not to add the /second-site and /third-site in the root directive as Nginx will automatically add requested subpaths to the root path at request.

If your folder structure is as follows:

```
/root_folder/*
/root_folder/second-site
/root_folder/third-site
```

You only need

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;

    root /root_folder/;

    location / {
        # code
    }
}
```

And Nginx will do the rest for you.